# Automatically filter accounts on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my `Account`s index page, I have a form at the top of the page with several `<select>`s that allow filtering. On the initial get request, I'd like to filter by the current `Staffer`, while maintaining the ability to select any `Staffer`. As the code is written below, the current `Staffer` is selected when the page loads, but this does not filter the results.

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_with url: accounts_path, scope: :filters, remote: true, method: :get, data: {controller: "filterable"} do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.select :staffer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Staffer.ordered, :id, :full_name, selected: current_staffer.id), {label: "Responsible Staffer", prompt: "Anyone"}, data: {action: "change->filterable#apply"} %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your controller you need to do the filtering before you display the page

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    staffer_id = params[:staffer_id].presence || current_staffer.id
    @accounts = Account.where(staffer_id: staffer_id)
  end
end
```